# How to handle transactions & persistence-context in Java EE correctly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions, glassfish, heap-memory

I am currently refactoring a bigger Java EE project involving Glassfish 4.0. Eclipse-Link 2.5 is used as JPA provider and there's no web-interface, only Java SE clients directly connecting to the EJB facades by JNDI lookups. The application runs correctly for a long time, but after 3-4 weeks we always get **heap overflow exceptions**.

I decided to profile heap memory at the point of the overflow event. Here's a snapshot of the heap ordered by packages:

[image: Snapshot of the heap at the moment of the HeapOverflowException event.]

The highlighted packages are mostly related to database connections... So I conclude that there must be a problem with transactions/database-connections/persistence-contexts that are not properly released. Btw, the package ***ch.lawsuite.model.dao*** contains our domain-model, i.e. the entity classes annotated with @Entity. These instances are probably built by the entity manager (persistence-context), but there's about 1.5 GB retained by those entity classes and the JPA classes although the raw database had a size of ~3 MB at this time.

Following I'll shortly describe the architecture of our application. This is a cutout of our persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" ... [abbreviated]">
  <persistence-unit name="LawSuiteEE-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/H2_DS</jta-data-source>
    [abbreviated - list of all @Entity classes - abbreviated]
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As you can see, we're using JTA (Java Transaction APIs) - but probably not the correct way. Here's a cutout of one of our typical facades in the EJB-module that we're using to access the database behind the application server from the clients:

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles("User")
public class AddressFacade extends AbstractFacade implements AddressFacadeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "LawSuiteEE-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("User")
    public Address create(Address address) {
        address= em.merge(address);
        em.persist(address);
        em.flush();
        em.refresh(address);
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("User")
    public Address queryById(String id) {
        TypedQuery<Address > query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.id = '"+id+"'", Address.class);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

Basically we want just one single persistence-context shared among all stateless session beans. Alternatively it would also be possible to construct/destruct the persistence-context after each method call on the facades. Application-Managed Persistence-Context versus Container-Managed Persistence-Context?

Some advice is highly appreciated :-) !

Answer (score 2):

Here's some observations:

- You don't need to do a merge and then a persist. Just do a persist to
  create a new address.
- This flush() is unnecessary as you are using
  CMT (container managed TXs) and the container will take care of
  flushing for you. flushing is expensive and it's much more efficient
  to let the container manage whenever possible.
- The refresh is unnecessary and expensive. The new address has already been persisted
- The query in your lookup code is not setting the ID parameter
- In your lookup method you call .getSingleResult() - this can throw a NoSuchResultException - and because your method does not declare it as part of the throws clause this leaves it as a hidden responsibility to consumers of the method. There are a couple of patterns people use for this and without debating their merits because it comes down to mostly a style issue I like to do something like the following:

  ```
  @Nullable
  @Override
  @RolesAllowed("User")
  public Address queryById(String id) {
      Address address;
      TypedQuery<Address > query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.id = '"+id+"'", Address.class);
      query.setParameter("id", id);
      try {
          address = query.getSingleResult();
      }catch(NoSuchResultException nrex) {
          address = null;
      }
      return address;
  }
  ```

  Using the @Nullable annotation makes it clear to the compiler, your IDE, and the client that this method might return null if no Address exists in the DB with the given ID.

In terms of your heap space issues you are going to have to do some more investigation as to what's holding on to references to these classes to see what's up. You probably have a leak in your application code.  I don't know what IDE/tools you use but the latest v14 EAP of Intellij IDEA will show you in the debugger all objects that are holding on to references to a particular object. I'm sure other profiling tools will do the same.  Also, your JPA provider will cache entities. Eclipselink has a L1 and L2 cache. You can control which entities are cached - All, none, some etc. You can also manually evict from the cache. Some of this may be cache consumption or you may have a leak in your code somewhere. There's some documentation here [1].

[1] - http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

Comment: +1 but sometimes you need to call `flush()` method if you need to use generated values (i.e.: ids) in the same transaction. Otherwise those won't be available until commit is performed. Doesn't seem to be the case though.

Comment: Hi NBW - thanks for your answer. Indeed, I flush and refresh the entity in order to update the auto-generated ID and pass it back to the client. The "merge" at the beginning of the create-method is linked to a DTO<->DAO conversion pattern. I already disable "caches" in Eclipse-Link, since it makes not much sense in a heavy multi-user scenario because of stale data. The NoSuchResultException is handled correctly in the original code, I just removed that part for the purpose of simplicity. Setting ID parameter is in this case not absolutely necessary.

Comment: But, finally the core question is not answered by you. I am looking for a way to avoid the HeapOverflowException and therefore need a solution that avoids creating multiple persistence contexts (which are blocking most of memory and implies the HeapOverflowException I think. How would I have to change the code to avoid that multiple persistence contexts are created by the Container-Managed Entity-Manager?

Comment: I'm not sure you can draw that, or any, conclusion from what I see here. Have you tried profiling the code over time to see what is growing the heap vs. the snap shot you have taken here. It could very well be the case that the eclipse related classes that you are focusing in on here aren't growing over time, or aren't the growth thats actually triggering the OOM.